# Is it possible for data to change within a transaction with repeatable read isolation?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

I have some .NET code wrapped up in a repeatable read transaction that looks like this:

```
using (
                var transaction = new TransactionScope(
                    TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                    new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead },
                    TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                int theNextValue = GetNextValueFromTheDatabase();
                var entity = new MyEntity
                               {
                                   Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                   PropertyOne = theNextValue, //An identity column
                                   PropertyTwo = Convert.ToString(theNextValue),
                                   PropertyThree = theNextValue,
                                   ...
                               };
                DbSet<MyEntity> myDbSet = GetEntitySet();
                myDbSet.Add(entity);
                await this.databaseContext.Entities.SaveChangesAsync();

                transaction.Complete();
            }
```

The first method, `GetNextValueFromTheDatabase`, retrieves the max value stored in a column in a table in the database.  I'm using repeatable read because I don't want two users to read and use the same value.  Then, I simply create an `Entity` in memory and call `SaveChangesAsync()` to write the values to the database.

Sporadically, I see that the values of entity.PropertyOne, entity.PropertyTwo, and entity.PropertyThree do not match each other.  For example, entity.PropertyOne has a value of 500, but entity.PropertyTwo and entity.PropertyThree have a value of 499.  How is that possible?  Even if the code weren't wrapped in a transaction, I would expect the values to match (just maybe duplicated across the Entities if two users ran at the same time).

I am using Entity Framework 6 and Sql Server 2008R2.

**Edit:**
Here is the code for `GetNextValueFromTheDatabase`

```
public async Task<int> GetNextValueFromTheDatabase()
{
    return await myQuerable
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.PropertyOne) //PropertyOne is an identity column (surprise!)
        .Select(x => x.PropertyOne)
        .Take(1)
        .SingleAsync() + 1;
}
```

Comment: This question is getting too weird, so the simple answer is YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  As described in [usr's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828975/4071814), multiple transaction can read the same max value at the same time (S-Lock).The problem was that one of the columns is an `identity` column.  EF allows you specify an identity column's value when inserting but ignores the value you specify.  So the identity column seemed to update with the expected value most of the time, but in fact the value specified in the domain entity just happen to match what the database was generating internally.

So for example, let's say the current max number is 499, transaction A and transaction B both read 499.  When transaction A finishes, it successfully writes 500 to all three properties.  Transaction B attempts to write 500 to all 3 columns.  The non-identity columns are updated successfully to 500, but the identity column's value is incremented to the next available value automatically (without throwing an error)

**A few solutions**

The solution I used is to not set the value for any of the columns when inserting the record.  Once the record is inserted, update the other two columns with the database assigned identity column's value.

Another option would be to change the column's option to  `.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)`
...which would perform better than the first option, but would require the changes usr suggested to mitigate the lock issues.

Answer (score 0):

So this question cannot be definitively answered because `GetNextValueFromTheDatabase` is not shown. I'm going off of what you said what it does:

`REPEATABLE READ` in SQL Server S-locks rows that you have read. When you read the current maximum, presumably from an index, that row is S-locked. Now, if a new maximum appears that row is unaffected by the lock. That's why the lock does not prevent other, competing maximum values from appearing.

You need `SERIALIZABLE` isolation if you obtain the maximum by reading the largest values from a table. This will result in deadlocks in your specific case. That can be solved through locking hints or retries.

You could also keep a separate table that stores the current maximum value. `REPEATABLE READ` is enough here because you always access the same row of that table. You will be seeing deadlocks here as well even with `REPEATABLE READ` without locking hints.

Retries are a sound solution to deadlocks.

Comment: But looking again at the query it got me confused. Those values could be wrong because of repeatable read and phantom reads happening. But how can they not mathch? If the function is called only once and the value is stored in a variable. Could/should not matching really happed because of something happening in other transactions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You might obtain 10 and another transaction inserts 11. Now you insert 11. That's a conflict.

Comment: Yes you might get two equal rows, but the question is about why PropertyOne and PropertyTwo does not sometimes match within one entity.

Comment: OK, I misread the question. The problem is that you are writing to one of the properties somewhere else. This is not diagnoseable with the code shown. None can answer this.

Comment: Was guilty myself, but I have seen some weird things happening with entity framework transactions. It would be funny if where really were no other transactions modifying these rows.

Comment: The properties are not being written to anywhere else, at least not within the transaction.  I'm a bit skeptical as to whether EF is propagating the transaction to the database as I expect.  I'll run sql profiler tomorrow to see.  Even if EF is not propagating the transaction correctly, I only retrieve the max value from the database one time, and I only write back to the database in the single SaveChangesAsync() call.

Comment: @whatevAR Well, if the code is what's written this cannot be. So there is a surprise somewhere. Profiling is a great next step. Why do you think transactions are the issue? When you insert (x, x) you expect to see two times x, no matter what the tran configuration is.; Also check the mapping.

Comment: @usr - thanks for the follow up and great initial answer.  The surprise is described in the answer I posted.  Essentially, EF was not inserting the value I specified for the identity column, but instead silently changing the value when there was a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are basically experiencing **the phantom read**.

Consider two transactions T1, T2 that are scheaduled for execution like shown below. The things is that in T1's first read you do not get value (X) that is inserted from transaction T2. In the second time you do get the value (X) in your select statement. This is the scary nature of the repeatable read. It does not block insertion in the whole table if some rows are read from it. It only locks existing rows.

```
T1                                     T2

SELECT A.X FROM WeirdTable

                                       INSERT INTO WeirdTable TABLE (A) VALUES (X)
SELECT A.X FROM WeirdTable
```

.

**UPDATE**

It seems that this answer turned out irrelavant for this specific question. It is related to the repeatable read isolation level, matches the keywords of this question and is not concepcually wrong though, so I will leave it in here.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that doesn't explain why I would have different values in different columns the same *table*.